# Mapping one custom Java field to many JSON fields using Jackson @JsonDeserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, hl7-fhir

I have a java class representing a JSON using Jackson. All of the fields, with one exception, can be translated using no annotations at all. 1-to-1, simple translations (although some of them are nested POJOs).

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyPojo {
    private String someString;
    private AnotherPojo someOtherPojo;
    //The problem child:
    private Object value;
}
```

The field `value` which is an exception to this rule, can represent any JSON field matching `value*` where `*` is a wildcard of indefinite length. That means `valueString` or `valueReference` in JSON will be assigned to this field with the assertion that only one may be present.

```
{
  "someString": "asdasdadasdsa",
  "someOtherPojo": {
    "someOtherProperty": "whatever"
  },
  "valueCodeableConcept": {
    "text": "text value",
    "coding": [
      {
        "code": "my-code"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Using a custom deserializer on the top-level class, I can scrape all of the fields from the root node (`baseNode` in the following example) that start with `value` and set the value field appropriately. That works great! However, in doing so, I now have to set every other field in this `MyPojo` class manually in my deserializer, and I have to put a custom copy of this deserializer on each POJO that uses a field like `value*`.

```java
private Object parseValueX(JsonNode baseNode, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
    //Find the concrete implementation referred to by the value[x] field
    Set<String> concreteNames = new HashSet<>();
    baseNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(name -> {
        if (name.startsWith("value")) {
            concreteNames.add(name);
        }});

    if (concreteNames.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    if (concreteNames.size() > 1) {
        throw JsonMappingException.from(context, "The field value[x] must have no more than one concrete " +
                "implementation, ex: valueCode, valueCodeableConcept, valueReference");
    }

    String concreteName = concreteNames.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(""));
    JsonNode jsonSource = baseNode.get(concreteName);

    //...deserialize from jsonSource, solved, but not relevant to question...
}
```

To make this apply to any `value*` property on any POJO, I tried to move the deserializer to the `value` attribute in the POJO (whereas it's on the top-level resource now). The first flaw is that the deserializer isn't even invoked unless the JSON property exactly matches `value`. What I actually need is for the entire parent JSON resource to be passed to that field-specific deserializer, so that I may find the matching field and assign it -- OR -- I need to be able to have the deserializer on `MyPojo` *only* assign the one field `value` and allow the automatic deserialization to take care of the others. How do I do either of these?

---

For those curious about my motivation, I am implementing the HL7 FHIR Specification, which specifies generic attributes called value[x] (here's one example: https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extensibility.html#Extension) where [x] becomes the type of the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good fit for you problem is [@JsonAnySetter](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations). This method annotation tells Jackson to route unknown properties to it. the arg (in your case) is a Map containing the json tree of the unknown property. if I understand your code properly, the name of the value property contains the class name of the target Pojo. so once you have a class name, you can tell Jackson how to "deserialize" the map into an instance of the target class.

Here is an example based on the code from the question

```
public class MyPojo {
    public String someString;  // made properties into public for this example...
    public AnotherPojo someOtherPojo;
    public Object value;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setValue(String name, Object value) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + value.getClass());
        System.out.println(value);

        // basic validation
        if (name.startsWith("value") && value instanceof Map) {
            String className = "com.company." + name.substring("value".length());
            System.out.println(name + " " + value.getClass() + " " + className);
            System.out.println(value);
            try {
                // nice of Jackson to be able to deserialize Map into Pojo :)
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                this.value = mapper.convertValue(value, Class.forName(className));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(this.value + " " + this.value.getClass());
        }

    }
}

public class AnotherPojo {
    public String someOtherProperty;
}

public class CodeableConcept {
    public String text;
    public Code[] coding;
}

public class Code {
    public String code;
}
```

Comment: That's fantastic, and the opposite annotation @JsonAnyGetter allows me to serialize this resource quite painlessly. I am going to implement this today and I will accept your answer should it work as intended.